# How is it possible to change the Filename, when using express-fileUpload?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, file-upload

How can I change the Filename of the File I uploaded to the Server?

```
app.post(URL, (req, res) => {
let fileName = req.files.file.name;
req.fileUpload;
res.statusCode = HTTP_OK;
res.send("Good Job")  })
```

I got this settings in uplodFile :

```
app.use(
fileUpload({
    createParentPath: true,
    useTempFiles : true,
    tempFileDir : "path",
})
```

);

The Code saves the file i"n the right directory but the name is something like "tmp-2-1654614752945".

Can somebody help ?

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post(URL, (req, res) => {
if (!req.files) {
  return res.status(400).send("No files were uploaded.");
}

const file = req.files.file;
const fileName = file.name
const path ="path" + fileName;

file.mv(path, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }
  testSelection.files = fileName;
  return res.send({ status: "success", path: path });
});
```

});